# How to compute 2-norm between two matrices of different sizes?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have a matrix $A$ of size $n\times8$ and matrix B of size $m\times8$. I need to compute $2$-norm to measure similarity.

It can be measured as: $d(A,B)= \frac{||A-B||_{2}}{||A||_{2} ||B||_{2}}$

Comment: Looking at your definition of $d(A,B)$, it's obvious that $A,B$ must have the same size for $A-B$ to be defined, and hence for $d(A,B)$ to be defined.

Comment: I studied in a sciencedirect Paper ..http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320313004093